# To show the route between mutliple points in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I want to show the exact route path between the more that two points.

I do have some example but all are having example which show the route between two points.

Exmaple :- [this](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions/downloads), [also this](https://github.com/Surya121/SBMapWithRoute/downloads)
even i had also gone through the example of regexlite.
But all have the logic for the route between two points.
Through polyline i can just draw the straight line.I am not able to see the route.

**EDITED QUESTION:-**

There are 5 points:-

1)points is :-"lat": -35.29987329273559,
                    "lng": 149.13395404815674,

2)Point is:- "lat": -35.2984416380826,
                    "lng": 149.13144886493683,

3)point is:-   "lat": -35.302576234486935,
                    "lng": 149.13335928744252,

4)point is:- "lat": -35.301081642089805,
                    "lng": 149.13073539733887,

5)point is :-"lat": -35.29991644393122,
                    "lng": 149.13659454104746,

Now i want to draw a route from point 1 to point 5.And route must contain all the points.
I know i can find the route between two points but how do i fire the one and same method again and again so find the route
Please help me.
Thank in advance

Comment: you need to draw route using MKPolyline to draw route between two points, did you try that?

Comment: If ou could make your question more clear, i think i can help you. Am currently working with MKMapView

Comment: I dont want to draw the route with only two points.I have multiple points.And want to draw the route with that..

Comment: using MKPolyline , you can pass only a start coordinate and stop coordinate, but why dont you try drawing multiple PolyLines step by step and add them as MKOverLays???

Comment: @Dpk I am editing the quesition which might make the clear idea.

Comment: @shweta please make use of chat option rather than long comments

Comment: @Rajneesh071 ios 6 as well as in ios 5

Comment: in ios 6 apple integrate new concept for route, it will show rout as show in ios 6 map application...

Answer (score 1):

**Apple** integrate new feature to show route.

**Requirement ->** OS version should be `IOS6`or later.

Show route from current location to `YourCoordinate` in `iOS6`

```
-(void)showMapRouteFromCurrentLocation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentUserCoordinate = YourCoordinate;
    //currentUserCoordinate.latitude=  +53.509980;
    //currentUserCoordinate.longitude =  -0.133700;

    MKPlacemark *place = [[MKPlacemark alloc]
                          initWithCoordinate:currentUserCoordinate
                          addressDictionary:nil];


    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:place];

    NSDictionary *routeOption = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];

    [mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:routeOption];
}
```

[Here](http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in) is the link of this.

Comment: hey bro i am able to get the directions and the map's app open but i am unable to go back to my app from where i went to find the directions.can u please suggest me to how can i call the map view inside my app's view or a way so that i can return to my app?? Thanks

Comment: @niks2000 -> i did not implemented this task if you can find then please let me know...

Comment: hmmm ..sure.. i am looking for the answer still .have u any idea about this??

Comment: didnot get u bro?? please can u provide me the link to that>?>? @Rajneesh071

Comment: https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr/tree/master/Examples/SnapAndRun-iPhone

Comment: Now instead of redirecting to the particular page, it redirecting to the home page.You have removed actual url